Azure DevOps release stuck but deployed
We host an asp.net core web application on Azure and we build and deploy the app through Azure DevOps.


The release has always worked, however in the last month we are experiencing a major problem.
The release, after a successfully completed build, on Devops remains  stuck in this state:

But on Portal Azure we can see that the release has been completed:

What's the problem here?

From your screenshot, the Azure App Service Deploy task stuck at log: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated., but the package has been deployed to the Web App successfully.
The cause of the issue could be that there are pending deployments record in the Azure Web App.
To solve this issue, you can keep the latest log record and remove all previous deployment logs(Especially the pending deployment status) in the Azure Web App Service -> Deployment Center -> Logs.
For example:

Then you can run the pipeline again and check if it can work.

Thank you very much! This problem was bugging me for years
